# Order of preference for SFINAE template?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to implement templated structs that take a version parameter.

Here's a simplified example:

```
template<int Version, class Enable = void>
struct Foo
{
};

template<int Version, class Enable = void>
struct Bar
{
};

/* Base Version of Foo */
template<int Version>
struct Foo<Version, typename enable_if<(Version > 0)>::type>
{
    int i;
};

/* Base Version of Bar */
template<int Version>
struct Bar<Version, typename enable_if<(Version > 0)>::type>
{
    Foo<Version> foo;
    float f;
};

/* Version 2 of Bar */
template<int Version>
struct Bar<Version, typename enable_if<(Version >= 2)>::type>
{
    Foo<Version> foo;
    float f;
    int extraParam;
};
```

With this approach, there is ambiguity when I use "Bar<2>", because 2 satisfies both the base version's condition (Version > 0) and the version 2 condition (Version >= 2).

I could change the base to require "Version > 0 && Version < 2", but I was hoping to avoid having to do that everywhere. Is there a better way to tell the compiler "Use the highest matching version" for a given template ?

Comment: ... you *can* use overload resolution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a8f5315c7599361 I tried something similar purely based on partial ordering, but somehow the enable_if interferes..

Comment: It's also possible to use recursion: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0a77e7b006264e

Comment: The recursion approach is fine, the overload resolution... meh :) The key that you forgot to mention is that for each new version you would have to add an additional argument to the selector.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True.. you could also use 42 ints and hope for the best ;) -- or you could use [Xeo's technique from here](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2013/03/11/overload-ranking.html) for the overload solution.

Comment: @dyp also notice that enable_if_t is useless in the recursion approach

Comment: @MarcoA. Oh, yes, that's an artefact. You can keep it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [example link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0a77e7b006264e) provided by [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp), I was able to solve the problem with recursion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<int Version>
struct Foo
{
    constexpr static bool is_valid = false;
};

template<int Version>
struct Bar
{
    constexpr static bool is_valid = false;
};

struct ValidVersion { constexpr static bool is_valid = true; };

/* Base Version of Foo */
template<>
struct Foo<0> : ValidVersion
{
    int i;
};

/* Base Version of Bar */
template<>
struct Bar<0> : ValidVersion
{
    Foo<0> foo;
    float f;
};

/* Version 2 of Bar */
template<>
struct Bar<2> : ValidVersion
{
    Foo<2> foo;
    float f;
    int extraParam;
    int extraParam2;
};

template<template<int V> class _Tp, int Version>
struct VersionSelectorImpl
{
    template<class T>
    struct wrap { using type = T; };
    using type = typename std::conditional<_Tp<Version>::is_valid, wrap<_Tp<Version>>, VersionSelectorImpl<_Tp, Version-1>>::type::type;
};

template<template<int V> class _Tp, int Version>
using VersionSelector = typename VersionSelectorImpl<_Tp, Version>::type;

int main() {
    cout << "sizeof(<Bar, 1>): " << sizeof(VersionSelector<Bar, 1>) << '\n';
    cout << "sizeof(<Bar, 2>): " << sizeof(VersionSelector<Bar, 2>) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> sizeof(<Bar, 1>): 12 
>      sizeof(<Bar, 2>): 16